# Git-Bash File Lookup Depending On File Type

Tags: bash, git, file, search

I am trying to navigate through all existing all branches and lookup if files with a certain extension such as (.zip or .exe exist)

I tried to write a bash script to achieve this task.

for branch in $(git branch);
do
    echo "I am in: $branch" 
    git ls-files *.exe
done

I would like to see the file path when it is detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is how I solved my problem:

```
read -p "Extension to lookup [example: .zip]: " extensionType

    for branch in $(git branch);
do
    if [[ $branch == *"Release"* ]]; then
    echo "----------------------------------"
    echo ">>Navigating to: $branch"
    echo ">>$branch..."
    git checkout $branch
    git ls-files "*$extensionType"
    echo "----------------------------------"
    fi
done
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are not changing to the branch so you are always checking the last branch you checked out.  Try this:

```
# In the repo's working directory
for branch in $(git branch -a|grep -v remotes|sed 's/\*//g'); do
  echo "I am in branch: ${branch}"
  git checkout ${branch}
  find . -type f -name '*.md'
done
```